# Unable to add value to cells in a "named" range in excel using VB.NET (what is wrong with this code?)

Tags: vb.net, excel, range

I am trying to implement following loop but I am not able to name the excel range.

```
Dim oXL As New Excel.Application      
Dim oWB13 As Excel.Workbook
oWB13 = oXL.Workbooks.Open("F:\mybook.xlsx")

With oWB13
For i = 1 To 2
  .Worksheets(i).Range("N102:XFD102").Name = "to_from"
    With oWB13.Worksheets(i)
       For j = 1 To 2
        .Range("to_from").Cells(102, 13 + j).Value = "K" & j
       Next
    End With
Next
End With

oXL.Visible = True
```

**Expected Result:**
Cells N102 and O103 in each worksheet in oWB13 should have names/value K1 and K2 respectively.

what is wrong here?

VB.NET understanding: intermediate

thanks

Comment: @TimWilliams, K1  isn't  being  used  as a  range  name,  only a  value.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do: <br>the result of your code is to set cells Sheet1!AA203:AB203 and Sheet2!AA203:AB203 to K1 and K2 and to have a single global Defined Name of 'to_from' referring to Sheet2!$N$102:$XFD$102

Comment: @doug - thanks.  Up too late last night...

Comment: @CharlesWilliams: Sorry for the confusion. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do:
the result of your code is to set cells Sheet1!AA203:AB203 and Sheet2!AA203:AB203 to K1 and K2 and to have a single global Defined Name of 'to_from' referring to Sheet2!$N$102:$XFD$102

If you want to set the values of N102 and O103 then 
.Range("to_from").Cells(102, 13 + j).Value = "K" & j
should read
.Range("to_from").Cells(j, j).Value = "K" & j
(the .Cells reference is within the Range)

but using a global defined name amd immediately redefining it like this is confusing at best: why not just use the range address?
.Range("N102:XFD102").Cells(j, j).Value = "K" & j